# Unable to use CAST AS RECORD on SELECT

Tags: string, casting, google-bigquery

I have a simple table with 2 columns: Col1 and Col2

```
sh-3.2# ./bq show --schema dataset.Test
[{"type":"STRING","name":"Col1","mode":"NULLABLE"},{"type":"STRING","name":"Col2","mode":"NULLABLE"}]
```

This Query works fine

```
SELECT * EXCEPT (Col2) , CAST(Col2 AS NUMERIC) AS Col2 FROM `project.dataset.Test` LIMIT 1000
```

This Query returns an error

```
SELECT * EXCEPT (Col2) , CAST(Col2 AS RECORD) AS Col2 FROM `project.dataset.Test` LIMIT 1000
```

Any ideas why?

I'm trying to use the keyword RECORD as appeared in the WebUI

[image]

Comment: Where do you see RECORD in https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types?

Comment: I see RECORD in the WebUI when trying to add new SCHEMA [
    {
        "mode": "NULLABLE",
        "name": "",
        "type": "RECORD"
    }
] Maybe I should use ARRAY or another keyword when running DML?

Comment: Can you update your question to show what your input data is and what your expected output is? It's hard to tell what you're hoping to achieve.

Comment: @ElliottBrossard question is updated with an image

Comment: What is your expected output? You can't use RECORD as a type name... it's another name for STRUCT, which is parameterized by field names and their types.

Comment: I wanted to change Col1 String to Col1 Struct (I was confused by the webUI RECORD option which I think is confusing). However reading this link I see this is not possible, https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/conversion_rules. Given that what is the best option to change a field from type String to STRUCT?

Comment: I still don't understand what it would mean to change a string to a struct. Maybe someone else will be able to help you.

Comment: @TamirKlein - just curious - what is the point in CASTing one string field into STRUCT - what is the practical use of it? I feel like something else actually behind this question that got lost!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BigQuery conversion rules do not allow you to convert from String to a Record (AKA Struct).

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/conversion_rules

You would have to compose the struct yourself within your query.  Something like this:

```
SELECT 
    * EXCEPT (Col2), 
    STRUCT( Col2 as inner_Col2) as my_inner_record 
FROM `project.dataset.Test` LIMIT 1000
```